# Calculated Column based on the other column which is of type choice in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, choice-field

I am very new to the whole SharePoint and excel formulas and I am in the process of learning.

I have a list in SharePoint in which I have multiple columns.

I want to create a calculated column based on the value provided in the other column.

My first column "Input Data" with multiple choice as Strings. "String1", "String2", "String3"
My second column "value" is a numeric column.

If I choose "String1", in the "Input Data" column then in the "value" column, I want a value 1
if I choose "String2", in the "Input Data" column then in the "value" column, I want a value 3
if I choose "String3", in the "Input Data" column then in the "value" column, I want a value 6

How do I write this?

I was initially trying to do it with one value

```
=if(([inputData])=="string1", 1,0)
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `inputData` is of type "Choice", use below formula:

```
=IF([inputData] = "String1", 1, 0)
```

If above formula throws "syntax error", use below:

```
=IF([inputData] = "String1"; 1; 0)
```

---

For multiple conditions, you can write nested `IF` conditions like:

```
=IF([inputData] = "String1", 1, IF([inputData] = "String2", 3, IF([inputData] = "String3", 6, 0)))
```

**Documentation**: [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

**Note**: Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I also did use the above syntax. But I get technical error. Apparently, I have to use German formula and syntax due to the region.